# How to pass a var in an mongodb query in node js

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want to pass a variable to the query, but I didn't find out how:

```
 db.collection('users').update(
  { "_id":ObjectID(req.params.id)},
  { $set:  { tasks[req.params.pos].done : true }}
  ,(error,resultat)=>{
       if (resultat){
         console.log("mise a jour avec succes ");
         res.send({message:"mise a jour avec succes "});
       } else {
         console.log("Erreur lors du mise a jour ");
         res.send({message:"Erreur lors du mise a jour "});
       }  

     });
```

and this is the mongodob document  I want to change the field done but with the index from a variable like : var x = 5  " task[x].done = true "

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a730e55114dbc2a0455c630"),
"email" : "unknown@gmail.com",
"password" : "unknown",
"tasks" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "new 5",
        "description" : "dod ododoododododo",
        "date" : "2018-02-07T18:25:14.881Z",
        "done" : false
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "new2",
        "description" : "dod ododoododododo",
        "date" : "2018-02-07T18:25:14.881Z",
        "done" : false
    }
]
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get with the current code?

Comment: You u can pass json you can not pass variable

Comment: Unexpected token +  ///___ 

Can't made a concatination in the $set

Comment: How can I pass a json instead of var ?

Comment: `let q = { 'tasks.' + req.params.pos + '.done': true}` and then `$set: q`

Comment: I tried {   let q }but still the same problem SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Comment: The problem that if I do like this 
_____db.collection('users').update(
      { "_id":ObjectID(req.params.id)},
       { $set: { tasks.0.done : true }}_______ it works fine

Comment: @NileshSingh that's a really bad idea.  String concatenation is not only poor performance, but opens up an attack vector, even in NoSQL databases.

Comment: @Paul It's not a suggestion on my side, just a modification to what the user was trying to do and yes, I agree that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution 
Thank You all for contributing  in solving this problem

```
connection((db)=>{

let tid = { ["tasks."+req.params.pos+".done"] : true };

let query = { "_id": ObjectID(req.params.id) };

db.collection('users').update(
  { "_id":ObjectID(req.params.id)},
  { $set:    tid}
  ,(error,resultat)=>{
       if (resultat){
         console.log("mise a jour avec succes ");
         res.send({message:"mise a jour avec succes "});
       } else {
         console.log("Erreur lors du mise a jour ");
         res.send({message:"Erreur lors du mise a jour "});
       }  

     });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) you need to use the positional `$` operator

```
    db.collection('users')
    .update({'tasks.title': 'new2'}, 
    {'$set': {'tasks.$.done': false}},
    (error,resultat)=>{...
```

Comment: Still the same problem 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Comment: The problem that if I do like this _____db.collection('users').update( { "_id":ObjectID(req.params.id)}, { $set: { tasks.0.done : true }}_______ it works fine

Comment: Look in answers i upload a picture to you

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the positional $ operator

Comment: This is the correct answer, [per the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).  Note that as this answer demonstrates, you *must* include the array field as part of the query.

Comment: I know but this can't solve my problem now I need to prohibit any task_name repetetion ! like it will be my Primary Key

Comment: Then I suggest you change your model design and use object references rather than embedding your task data